# Laravel: Unable to use include(app_path()) in PHPunit tests

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit

I am trying to run unit tests on custom functions that I have in a file '\app\Custom\custom.php`

I am trying to include the custom file in my test file with:

```
include(app_path().'/Custom/custom.php');
```

but I get the error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Container\Container::path()
```

As per `@habeebdev`'s answer, I have tried:

file path added to `composer.json`

```
...
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/",
            "Database\\Factories\\": "database/factories/",
            "Database\\Seeders\\": "database/seeders/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        },
        "files": ["app/Custom/custom.php"]
    },
...
```

`laravel/tests/Unit/PracticeTest.php`

```
<?php

namespace Tests\Unit;

use Tests\TestCase;
use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class PracticeTest extends TestCase
{
    /**
     * A basic unit test example.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function test_trueExample()
    {

        $user = User::find(1);

        $this->actingAs($user)
             ->assertEquals(true, can_transact());

    }
}
```

error:

```
 Call to undefined function Tests\Unit\can_transact()
```

EDIT:

I had a `namespace App\Http\Controllers` in my `custom.php` file. Once I prefixed my functions `App\Http\Controllers\can_transact()` it worked fine (Thanks @apokryfos)

Answer (score 2):

You have to autoload the custom file. For this, please include custom.php in the 'autoload-dev' section of composer.json

```
"autoload-dev": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Tests\\": "tests/"
     },
     "files": ["app/Custom/custom.php"]
},
```

Run `composer dump-autoload`

Now you can call the custom function in your test script. No need to include the file.

---

Regarding the namespace, please change your custom.php namespace to `App\Custom`. Using Controller namespace for custom file is not good. Also, I recommend you to go through OOP and laravel basics.

Comment: I'd go one step further to say that if you find yourself needing to manually include these kinds of files and are using composer then something is wrong.

Comment: Hi, I have added the line to composer.json and run `composer dump-autoload` which completes ok. However when I call the function in the test I still get `Call to undefined function`

Comment: @apokryfos can you elaborate please.

Comment: @matt please post your test script as well as composer.php

Comment: please see above

Comment: what about custom.php? is the file at `app/Custom/custom.php`? and it contains `can_transact()` function?

Comment: @matt you need to make sure that your composer autoloader is the only thing included. After that composer will be responsible for all other includes

Comment: @apokryfos I don't understand what you mean

Comment: Note the `bootstrap` line in [phpunit.xml](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/8.x/phpunit.xml#L4) you should make sure that when phpunit runs it is using this configuration file. It should by default but if not sure use `phpunit -c phpunit.xml` (assuming your phpunit.xml is in the same directory you're running the command from)

Comment: @apokryfos the bootstrap line is `bootstrap="vendor/autoload.php` do I need to change this?

Comment: @apokryfos note that `'b32df3b3de6020a4122ade9802291209' => $baseDir . '/app/Custom/custom.php',` now exists in the `compsoer/autoload_files.php`

Comment: @matt the line is correct and if phpunit is reading the .xml file correctly it should allow you to use the composer autoloader

Comment: @apokryfos I notice that it is trying to look for the method in `Tests\Unit`, is there something that I am doing wrong?

Comment: @matt you probably should update your question with the code in your `custom.php` but it's possible the file is namespaced and therefore you need to refer to functions declared in it by providing that namespace the same way you would with classes

Comment: @matt run `composer dump-autoload`. please update your question with composer.php source code.

Comment: @apokryfos you nailed it with the namespace issue

Comment: habeebdev it was a namesspace issue. If you add that to your answer I can accept it

Comment: @matt yes.. that's why we asked custom.php source code..